# Are there any advantages or disadvantages for having mixed weapon squads?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have several melee squads in my current Dwarf Fortress game. These squads use a mix of melee weapons to have fun, swords, axes, maces.

Are there any advantages or disadvantages of using a mixed melee squad, instead of for example using a squad of only axe dwarfs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The possible advantages are that against some heavy armored enemies, mixed damage will improve your possibilities of breaking through the armor. Some enemies are almost immune to slashing or bashing damage. So if the whole squad engage that enemy, they won't waste time hitting with no damage.

The same applies in the opposite way: if you have the correct type of weapon, you will deal more damage to enemies with an armor weak to that kind of damage.